# Wordpress - how to invoke the default page template for custom generated content?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed an interceptor to render custom pages when matching user-defined slugs. The user can define these pages and their slugs, which I store in a table.

My question is this: how to include the default template (for the current theme) for a page around this dynamic content? It should behave exactly like the user had gone to "new page" and entered this content manually.

My first effort was to include the header, side bar and footer like so (`$myhtml` contains the custom html content to emit):

```
get_header();
print $myhtml;
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

This however had results inconsistent with using the normal page template, and makes some assumptions on how the theme template for page is structured.

Is there another method to render the default page template with my supplied content? Something like this? And what is the base practice here?

```
render_with_page_temaplte($myhtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do it this way, instead of just creating standard WordPress pages.

But you should look in your theme for `page.php` - this will have the structure used for displaying each page. Replace `the_content()` with your `$myhtml` variable and it should be close to what you want.

Comment: When the current theme is changed his users will end up seeing nothing. He will have to create a new child theme page.php whenver the site's theme is changed. i.e. Your solution is actually the problem he wants to solve!

Comment: He asked how to do it for the current theme, so that's what my answer was based on

Answer (score 0):

+1 as I'm also after a theme independent custom page solution - but in your case it might not be necessary if you don't need to alter <head> meta tags etc and you can unambiguously identify user slugs then something like the following may be a solution for you.

Concept only, as I also need to alter meta tags it's of no use to me so I've not tested and may have missed something that prevents it working:

1. create a new normal page named say "users" via page editor with its only contents being your shortcode (see below). e.g. [my_user_html]
2. in your site functions plugin or your replacement for custom page plugin (create one if necessary) and add the following:

Create a page rewrite rule:

```
function user_rewrite_rules($rules) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  //  AFTER ACTIVATING THIS PLUGIN YOU NEED TO RE_SAVE PERMALINKS ON DASHBOARD TO LOAD THIS REWRITE RULE
  $user_rule = array(
      'users/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=' . 'users' . '&usersslug=$matches[1]'
    );
  return array_merge($user_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'user_rewrite_rules');
```

This will "convert" a request for "*example.com/users/david*" into "example.com/index.php?pagename=users&usersslug=david" Note: anything after "users/" will now be in "usersslug" e.g. "david" or "david/films"

We need to make Wordpress aware of the query variable. So:

```
function my_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'usersslug';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars_filter' );
```

Add your my_user_html shortcode functionality

```
function user_insert_in_post($attrs, $content = null) {
  $my_params = get_query_var('usersslug');
  // then use $my_params to determine html to show etc
}
add_shortcode('my_user_html', 'user_insert_in_post');
```

3. Activate plugin and then from Dashboard save Permalinks (updates them for your user rewrite rule)